# compare sum from chunk from array to the previous chunk in rust

Tags: rust

I have a `let mut arr = vec![100,200,300,400,500,600];` and want to compare chunk of sum

chunkA: `100+200+300 = 600`
chunkB: `200+300+400 = 900`

compare `chunkA` and `chunkB`

Comment: Are the chunks constant-sized, or the vec has two chunks always?

Comment: chunks are constant 3 elements each, there will be chunkC also `[300, 400, 500]` and so on

Comment: i want to compare current chunk with the previous one

Comment: And what comparison do you want to perform? For example, do you want to check if chunks sum are sorted? What will be the end result?

Comment: I'd go with a combination of [`windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) to create the "chunks" and [`fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) for processing.

Comment: if `currentChunk > preChunk `

Comment: And what with three chunks and more?

Comment: finally, I want a `count` of how many such chunks are there which are greater than the previous one?

Comment: This statement lacks of a proper question and it's unclear what is even your problem. The comments should give you a hint that you really should try to improve the way you write your questions.

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over overlapping chunks in a slice, use [`windows()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows). To process pairs of chunks, you can use itertools' [`tuple_windows()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;

for (prev, current) in v.windows(3).tuple_windows() {
    // ...
}
```

If you want some accumulated result, I'd recommend going with [`Iterator::fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) (or [`Iterator::reduce()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.reduce)).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
fn main(){
    let arr = vec![100,200,300,400,500,600];
    println!("{}", arr.windows (3).fold ((None, 0),  |(prev, count), w| {
        let s = w.iter().sum::<i32>();
        (Some (s),
         if let Some (prev) = prev {
             if s > prev { count + 1 } else { count }
         } else {
             0
         })
    }).1);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=78958a8255518a0915e2ab61435b4802)

It uses [`slice::windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) to create the "chunks", then [`Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) to process them.

Or equivalently:

```
fn main() {
    let arr = vec![100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600];
    let mut chunks = arr.windows (3);
    println!(
        "{}",
        chunks
            .next()
            .map(
                |first| chunks.fold ((first.iter().sum::<i32>(), 0), |(prev, count), w| {
                    let s = w.iter().sum::<i32>();
                    (s, if s > prev { count + 1 } else { count })
                })
            )
            .unwrap_or ((0, 0))
            .1
    );
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f146d25a71716959f49d89611207699a)